# Spring MVC multi module jsp and controller not mapping properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

This is a simple Spring MVC multi module project, here I want to give request from index.jsp via action “showlogin.do” and then load login.jsp via LoginController.java.

I am trying to build WAR file and then want to run on Tomcat Server. On running in tomcat server it is showing index.jsp but when I click on link (showlogin.do) it gives me error like HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.

**URLs –**

1. Run WAR in Tomcat - http://localhost:8080/Biotech-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

Blockquote

2. After clicking on link it redirects to - http://localhost:8080/Biotech-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/showlogin.do

**Folder Structure –**

Biotech-test [Parent]

Biotech-data [Repository]

Biotech-service [Service], pom.xml has dependency of repository

Biotech-web, pom.xml has dependency of service

***index.jsp [Biotech-web: src/main/webapp/index.jsp]***

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>WELCOME</h3>
<a href="showlogin.do" target="_blank">Click here to login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

***web.xml [Biotech-web: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml]***

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

***tiles.xml [Biotech-web: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ tiles.xml]***

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseTemplate" id="baseTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/layout/baselayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Biotech"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layout/jsp/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="${body}"/>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/jsp/footer.jsp"/>
    </definition>
    <definition name="login" id="login" extends="baseTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="title" type="string" value="Login Page" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

***dispatcher-servlet.xml [Biotech-web: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]***

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pack.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pack.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pack.repository" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

***LoginController.java [com.pack.controller]***

```
package com.pack.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/showlogin")
    public String showlogin() {
        System.out.println("--------------login Controller----------");     
        return "login";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request mapping has just `/showlogin`, it should be `/showlogin.do`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried this @RequestMapping("/showlogin.do") but not working.